# fab for change maptype does nothing when I click

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I'm trying to create a fab that when clicked changes my map to terrain type. I set the map to open as satellite instead of default. The button appears but when clicked does nothing.

I set my maptype in onMapReady:

```
    private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->

         googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
```

And call my fab in onViewCreated:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)

        val fab = binding?.fab
        fab?.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(view: View?) {
                    if (GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID == googleMap.mapType) {
                        googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN
                    }else {
                    googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
                }
            }
        })
```

in layout XML file  is define like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_dashboard"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_layers_24"
        app:backgroundTint="#70FFFFFF"
        app:borderWidth="100dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know that this conditional is working properly?: "GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID == googleMap.mapType" <- I would use two differing log statements to make sure that conditional is doing what you want to troubleshoot this: if (GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID == googleMap.mapType) {
                        googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN
                    }else {
                    googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
                }

Comment: How are you initialising ``binding``? You're only setting a click listener if it's not null, and ``onViewCreated`` is where you'd typically initialise it (with ``binding = LayoutNameBinding.bind(view)``), or in ``onCreateView`` (with ``LayoutNameBinding.inflate``) - with either of those you know it's not null. I'd drop some log commands to make sure ``binding?.fab`` isn't null, and in the ``onClick`` so you know it's firing (or use the debugger which is way easier for checking what's going on!)

Comment: thanks for the considerations, i'm very new to android... so i'm not sure it's working but logically it should... or not? about the binding was the way I found to call the fab. findViewById doesn't work for me. if you have any suggestions on how to make this work... I don't necessarily need that same code.